# Bulk update in the elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to update a nested document (bulk) in the elasticsearch 5.X

Conditions

1. I will have multiple document with the same groupid.
2. I want to update the document's groupname which bares the groupid 244
3. I have to update them in bulk.

Eg: `{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_id": "1",
                "_source": {
                    "ticketdesc": [{
                        "groupid": 244,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_id": "2",
                "_source": {
                    "ticketdesc": [{
                        "groupid": 244,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_id": "3",
                "_source": {
                    "ticketdesc": [{
                        "groupid": 244,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_id": "4",
                "_source": {
                    "ticketdesc": [{
                        "groupid": 245,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    }]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do so easily with the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {"groupid": 245}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.groupname = 'New name' "
  }
}
```

Comment: i have already figured this out. Thanks for this. I have an another question how can i update if it has multiple block in one _id                                                                {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_id": "2",
                "_source": {
                    "ticketdesc": [{
                        "groupid": 244,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    },{
                        "groupid": 245,
                        "groupname": "Fire and run"
                    }]
                }
            }

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question if you got this one sorted out

Comment: i did.. feel free to answer that one too.. Thanks